# Split() in java

Tags: java, string, split

How to split string on the basis on escape sequence() in java.
Like :

```
String a ="23\\45\\20";
String b[]=a.split("\\");//this doesn't work
```

What is best way to do this.

Comment: If you created your string `a` like that, then it doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to `\` is escape character in both `Java` and `Regex Expression`, so you just need to use `\\\\` instead of `\\`

```
String b[]=a.split("\\\\");
```

`\\\\` in java will convert to `\\`

`\\` in regex will convert to `\`

Answer (score 3):

There are no backslash characters in this string:

```
String a ="23\45\20";
```

That's because `\45` and `\20` are seen as octal escape sequences, which expand to `%` and an unprintable `\x16` character respectively.

Escape these backslashes to get the desired effect:

```
String a ="23\\45\\20";
```

Comment: Ri8,Thanks for pointing out that.